# What to use to store in postgresql a string with no specific upper limit?

Tags: postgresql

On the postgresql manual page:
If you desire to store long strings with no specific upper limit, use text or character varying without a length specifier.

My question is: when to use which ? Or it doesn't matter ?

Comment: According to the manual, they have the same performance, so apparently there is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. Use what you prefer :)

Although `text` is not SQL standard I prefer it because is sorter.